# Loading XML encoded HTML into a WebView control

Tags: c#, html, xml, microsoft-metro

I have some HTML which is encoded as XML, for example:

```
html = "this is a test &lt;/a&gt; test &lt;em&gt;test2&lt;/em&gt; ... "
```

So when I try to load this into a `WebView` control, it doesn't correctly render the HTML:

```
myWebView.NavigateToString(html);
```

Just to be clear, I am not creating this HTML in this fashion, but am stuck with it.  Is there a way to either render this to the control, or convert it to standard HTML first?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
string html = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode("this is a test &lt;/a&gt; test &lt;em&gt;test2&lt;/em&gt; ... ");
```

Comment: Thanks - you put me on the right track, although this question relates to WinRt (HttpUtility is not available).  However, in the consumer preview it has now been moved to `System.Net.WebUtility`.